# Parsing XML response of SOAP web service with RPG and HTTPLIB

Tags: xml, soap, websphere, rpgle, rpg

I want to parse this xml response with **ILE RPG (Fully-Free RPG)** in a data structure with a field for currency and a field for the value.

Thats my response from soap webservice:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse xmlns="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult>&lt;MNBCurrentExchangeRates&gt;&lt;Day date="2021-12-09"&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="AUD"&gt;231,49&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="BGN"&gt;187,05&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="BRL"&gt;58,41&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="CAD"&gt;254,93&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="CHF"&gt;350,64&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="CNY"&gt;50,92&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="CZK"&gt;14,38&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="DKK"&gt;49,20&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="EUR"&gt;365,85&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="GBP"&gt;426,84&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="HKD"&gt;41,45&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="HRK"&gt;48,61&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="100" curr="IDR"&gt;2,25&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="ILS"&gt;104,13&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="INR"&gt;4,28&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="ISK"&gt;2,48&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="100" curr="JPY"&gt;284,60&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="100" curr="KRW"&gt;27,50&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="MXN"&gt;15,41&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="MYR"&gt;76,66&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="NOK"&gt;36,17&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="NZD"&gt;219,85&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="PHP"&gt;6,41&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="PLN"&gt;79,17&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="RON"&gt;73,91&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="RSD"&gt;3,11&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="RUB"&gt;4,39&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="SEK"&gt;35,70&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="SGD"&gt;236,93&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="THB"&gt;9,66&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="TRY"&gt;23,50&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="UAH"&gt;11,93&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="USD"&gt;323,22&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate unit="1" curr="ZAR"&gt;20,47&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;/Day&gt;&lt;/MNBCurrentExchangeRates&gt;</GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult>
        </GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The currencies are separated just with **&lt**. 
I tried it like this, but my variable xmlout is empty after the xml-into.

```
dcl-ds xmlout qualified;
  Tempout char(2129);
END-DS;   

xml-into xmlout %xml(postResult: 'case=any ns=remove allowextra=yes +
    path=Envelope/Body/GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse/GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult');
```

So how can I change or extend my to code to get all the currencies and their values into a structured ds?

Comment: Everything would be easier if they put XML in the SOAP (XML) payload, rather than escaped stringified XML string that needs to be unescaped and parsed, instead of just some simple XPath of what should be one big XML payload.....

Comment: Lazy developers do this because they don't want to figure out how to process `xs:any` and would rather have it just say that they will make the payload `xs:string` and make it someone elses problem

Comment: find a better built webservice?

Comment: Yes would be nice, but the customer want to to use exactly this one…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first XML-INTO, code xmlout.TempOut instead of just xmlout. In the XML document, GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult doesn't match a data structure.

Then you'd need a second XML-INTO to parse the new XML document in xmlout.TempOut.

Something like this, although varchar is probably not the right data type for everything.

```
dcl-ds MNBCurrentExchangeRates qualified;
   dcl-ds day;                           
      date date(*iso);                   
      num_rate int(10);                  
      dcl-ds rate dim(500);              
         unit varchar(10);               
         curr varchar(10);               
         value varchar(20);              
      end-ds;                            
   end-ds;                               
end-ds; 
                       
xml-into MNBCurrentExchangeRates 
         %xml(xmlout.Tempout  
            : 'case=any countprefix=num_ datasubf=value');
```

Tip: When developing a new XML-INTO, avoid using the allowextra or allowmissing options at first. Use a simplified version of the document without any extra or missing XML items until your data structure matches the XML document in general. If you code allowextra=yes or allowmissing=yes too soon, XML-INTO will accept almost anything without giving any error messages.

Comment: Thanks Barbara, I did it like you said now it's working :)